# how to use mounted in Flutter bloc cubit

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below method:

```
  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    CellsResponse cellsResponse;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      String platformVersion = await CellInfo.getCellInfo;
      final body = json.decode(platformVersion);

      cellsResponse = CellsResponse.fromJson(body);

      CellType currentCellInFirstChip = cellsResponse.primaryCellList[0];
      if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "LTE") {
        mcc =
            "LTE mcc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.lte.network.mcc.toString();

        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.lte.network.mnc.toString();
      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "NR") {
        mcc =
            "NR mcc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.nr.network.mcc.toString();
        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.nr.network.mnc.toString();
      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "WCDMA") {
        mcc = "WCDMA mcc = " +
            currentCellInFirstChip.wcdma.network.mcc.toString();
        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.wcdma.network.mnc.toString();

      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "GSM") {
        mcc = currentCellInFirstChip.gsm.network.mcc.toString();
        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.gsm.network.mnc.toString();

        print('currentMCC = ' + mcc);
        print('currentCqi = ' + mnc);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      _cellsResponse = null;
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
      _cellsResponse = cellsResponse;
      emit(AppSetCellResponseState());
  }
```

which Have a problem in the below part:

```
    if (!mounted) return;
      _cellsResponse = cellsResponse;
      emit(AppSetCellResponseState());
```

So I am using here Cubit instead setState, as I found the error `Undefined name 'mounted'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.`

it works fine when using setState in the stateful widget, so how to use `mounted` in the Cubit class?

Comment: are you running this code inside any widget like statefulwidget?

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari actually it is inside cubit class

Comment: mounted is a boolean getter from State class. You can use the context of the class where you want to check for

Comment: @Prabhanshu Tiwari I have solved it you can check the answer thanks for your support :)

Comment: Great!  Keep questioning

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution, just add the below lines before the method:

```
  StatefulElement _element;
  bool get mounted => _element != null;
```